# PostgreSQL CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not showing the correct time

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've tried getting the current time. This is what the code I run:

```
SELECT to_char(clock_timestamp() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Jakarta', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS clock_timestamp
```

But this is what I got, which is different from the actual time:
2022-06-15 19:51:46

See attached image for reference.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knZUc.png)

I've attached the timezone as well but it's showing the wrong time. Does anyone have any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The clock_timestamp() function is already returning a timestamp WITH a timezone. There is no need to convert to UTC in your `SELECT` statement.

A more detailed explanation can be found in the docs of the `AT TIME ZONE` operator at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT.

When you use the `AT TIME ZONE` operator on a timestamp with a timezone, the resulting type is timestamp without a timezone (per the docs). By adding a second `AT TIME ZONE` operator, you take a timestamp without a timezone and make it a timestamp with a timezone. In that double conversion, you lose and then add timezones but the offset math is reverse of what you think it is. Effectively, what you are doing is subtracting the timezone offset instead of adding it, which is why Jakarta looks like it is behind UTC when it should be ahead.

As an aside, are you sure you really want to use clock_timestamp() instead of current_timestamp()?